# How to select item from two different Listbox on Single click

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am able to achieve this on `Double Click`.

Here is my `sample code`.

### Sample Image On Signle Click

[image]

### Sample Image on Double Click

[image]

**Some Explanation of my code:**

1. I have created two listbox : `list_box_one`, `list_box_two`
2. And scrolling both widget at a single time.
3. And I want to select item from both listbox on single click.

```py
import tkinter as tk


class App:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()

        self.scroll = tk.Scrollbar(orient="vertical", command=self.Onscroll)
        self.scroll.pack(side="right", fill="y")

        self.list_box_one = tk.Listbox(self.root,
                                       borderwidth=0,
                                       yscrollcommand=self.scroll.set)
        self.list_box_one.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
        self.list_box_one.config(exportselection=False,
                                 highlightthickness=0,
                                 selectbackground='red')
        self.list_box_one.bind("<MouseWheel>", self.OnMouseWheel)
        self.list_box_one.bind('<Double-Button-1>', self.fileSelection)

        self.list_box_two = tk.Listbox(self.root,
                                       borderwidth=0,
                                       yscrollcommand=self.scroll.set)
        self.list_box_two.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
        self.list_box_two.config(exportselection=False,
                                 highlightthickness=0,
                                 selectbackground='red')
        self.list_box_two.bind("<MouseWheel>", self.OnMouseWheel)
        self.list_box_two.bind('<Double-Button-1>', self.fileSelection)

        for i in range(100):
            self.list_box_one.insert("end", "item %s" % i)
            self.list_box_two.insert("end", "item %s" % i)
        self.root.mainloop()

    def Onscroll(self, *args):
        self.list_box_one.yview(*args)
        self.list_box_two.yview(*args)

    def OnMouseWheel(self, event):
        self.list_box_one.yview_scroll(-1 * int(event.delta / 120), "units")
        self.list_box_two.yview_scroll(-1 * int(event.delta / 120), "units")
        return "break"

    def fileSelection(self, event):
        widget = event.widget
        index = widget.curselection()[0]  # Index Of Selected Item

        self.list_box_two.selection_clear(0, 'end')  # Clear Old Selected Item
        self.list_box_one.selection_clear(0, 'end')  # Clear Old Selected Item
        self.list_box_one.selection_set(index)  # Selecting Current Item
        self.list_box_two.selection_set(index)  # Selecting Current Item


app = App()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace `<Double-Button-1>` by `<<ListboxSelect>>` in the two `bind(...)`.

Also add the following two lines at the end of `fileSelection()` function:

```
self.list_box_one.see(index)
self.list_box_two.see(index)
```

Comment: Hello @acw1668 sir can you please solve my latest question.